# Initramfs error whenever booting Ubuntu after booting windows

Tags: dual-boot, initramfs

I've got a dual boot of Ubuntu with windows and Ubuntu and occasionally I use windows for things that I need to do and every time I seen to do that, it causes an initramfs error which says
`Error: no pointer back to namespace node in package 0000000`
I know the basic fix to this `sudo update-initramfs -u` which works temporarily but then the error comes back every time I boot windows then Ubuntu.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem? I know it can be ignored but it is concerning and annoying to put up with. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, this worked (sorry for late response, forgot about the question for a while)

Comment: Note: I updated a typo in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu**

Do these commands:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # we create a new ramdisk

`reboot` # we reboot the computer

**BIOS**

Disable Secure Boot.

**Windows**

We disable fast boot and hibernation:

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: Note: I updated a typo in my answer.